# Need to remove a particular file of size 0 from a directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

Need to remove a particular file of size 0 from directory, can anyone help me on that?

The code i have tried is

```
  for f in source_images:
    file_path = os.path.join(SOURCE_DIR,f)
    size = os.path.getsize(file_path)
    if size == 0:
      print(f'{f} is zero length, so ignoring')
      os.remove(file_path)
```

The error i am getting afterwards is below

```
/usr/lib/python3.7/shutil.py in copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks)
    118         os.symlink(os.readlink(src), dst)
    119     else:
--> 120         with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
    121             with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
    122                 copyfileobj(fsrc, fdst)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/PetImages/Dog/11702.jpg'

Any suggestion to overcome this!
```

Comment: How is `source_images` defined? Does `11702.jpg` exist?

Comment: yes it exist in source_images

Comment: @zille_elahi check folder/file access permissions

Comment: File have permission as i can copy rest of the other files from source directory to destination directory. End goal is to omit these zero sized files. Thanks

Comment: the code you posted, which looks fine btw,  isn't the portion that is throwing the exception and is not causing any issues.